# GridBagLayout alignment issue

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I use the `GridBagLayout` for creating a panel.

I would like the delete icon on the right corner of the panel. However, if the `JTextArea` is not added to the panel, the delete icon will shift to the left.

How to do it properly?

[image: rendered]

There is my code for GridBagLayout panel setting

```
public void setting() {
    try {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;  // **** comment this line out to see effect ****
        c.weighty = 1.0;  // **** comment this line out to see effect ****
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        addMouseListener(this);
        buildTopJPane();
        setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Utility.DisplayErrorMsg(pageErrorPrefix + err.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
```

There is the code for adding components into the panel

```
private void buildTopJPane() {

    try {


        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        this.add(setAttonIconCreator(), c);

        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        this.add(setDeleteIcon(), c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        this.add(setPageDateLabel(), c);

        if (thisComment.content != null) {
            if (thisComment.content.length() > 0)
                c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            c.gridwidth = 4;
            this.add(setContent(), c);
        }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Utility.DisplayErrorMsg(pageErrorPrefix + err.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of `weightx` and `anchor` on the delete icon.

For example, try using `weightx = 1` and `anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST`.  Note, this will also push the other content to the left.

You could also try using `weightx = 1` on the comment panel instead.

You may also find better use of `gridwidth` and cell placement allows you to overlap components across columns which will give you a better result.

Don't forget to reset the constraints before you use them on the next component.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I set  GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST on delete icon and it place on the right top corner.